# Modern Warfare 3 Killstreaks and Strike Packages

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

What killstreak rewards are available in Modern Warfare 3 (for all three strike packages)?  What does each one "do"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is new in Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34169/what-is-new-in-call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3)

Comment: @TomWijsman - that question does not go into detail for any of the strike packages.

Answer (score 3):

[Assault Strike Packages](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Assault_Strike_Package) will give bonuses that involve killing more opponents.

[Support Strike Packages](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Support_%28Strike_Package%29) wil give bonuses that involve supporting you own team.

The [Specialist Strike Package](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Specialist_%28Strike_Package%29) will give you additional perks at 2, 4, and 6 kills.  The order and type of these perks are determined by the order you select them in.